# Convert SRGB texture to linear in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, colors, 3d

I am currently trying to properly implement gamma correction in my renderer. I have set my framebuffer to be SRGB with `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB)` and now I am left with importing the SRGB textures properly. I know three approaches to do this:

1. Convert value in shader: `vec3 realColor = pow(sampledColor, 2.2)`
2. Make OpenGL do it for me: `glTexImage2D(..., ...,`***`GL_SRGB`***`, ..., ..., ..., GL_RGB, ..., ...);`
3. Convert the values directly:

   ```
   for (GLubyte* pixel = image; pixel < image + size; ++pixel) 
       *pixel = GLubyte(pow(*pixel, 2.2f) + 0.5f);
   ```

Now I'm trying to use the third approach, but it doesn't work.

1. It is super slow (I know it has to loop through all the pixels but still).
2. It makes everything look completely wrong (see image below).

Here are some images.

1. No gamma correction:
   [image]
2. Method 2 (correction in when sampling in fragment shader)
   [image]
3. Something weird when trying method 3
   [image]

So now my question is what's wrong with method 3 cause it looks completely different from the correct result (assuming that method 2 is correct, which if I think it is).

Comment: "*I am left with importing the SRGB textures properly*" Are the images in the sRGB colorspace or not? That is, is the image data in the files sRGB? Lastly, I don't see the point in either option 1 or option 3. Option 1 loses linear filtering, since it does filtering in sRGB which numerically is nonsense. Option 3 loses compression, since you either will have to use a larger bitdepth for your images after conversion to linear or you will lose precision in the values of the pixels.

Comment: @NicolBolas I meant, that now the only thing I have to do is to import the textures properly. I am pretty sure they're SRGB because they are albedo and gloss maps and I read that these textures are most commonly SRGB. As to why I don't use option 2, it is because I store all textures in a Texture2dArray for performance. But the problem is that, as far as I know, all layers must have the same `internalFormat` and not all textures are SRGB, like normal maps.

Comment: Nobody's forcing you to put *all* of your textures in the same array texture. You can have two or even 3 array textures. And it's not like your shader doesn't know when it's trying to read a normal map vs. a diffuse color. The point of collating textures is to reduce the number of state changes; using more than 1 array texture doesn't change that, because you don't have to actually change any of that state between different draws.

Comment: @NicolBolas I was planning to look into having multiple (preferable sparse and bindless) texture2dArrays, but I wanted to make something working first. Now however, I think it is a good time to check it out, because not being able to have textures of different sizes is starting to be annoying for me anyway. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have set my framebuffer to be SRGB with glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);

That doesn't set your framebuffer to a sRGB format - it only enables sRGB conversion *if* the framebuffer is using an sRGB format already - they only use of the `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` enable state is to actually *disable* sRGB conversion on frambeuffers which have an sRGB format. You still have to specifically request your windows' default framebuffer to be sRGB capabable (or might be lucky to get one without asking for it, but that will differ greatly on implementations and platforms), or you have to create an sRGB texture or render-target if you render to an FBO.

> 3. Convert the values directly:
>
>    ```
>    for (GLubyte* pixel = image; pixel < image + size; ++pixel) 
>          *pixel = GLubyte(pow(*pixel, 2.2f) + 0.5f);
>    ```

First of all `pow(x,2.2)` is *not* the correct formula for sRGB -  the real one uses a small linear segment near 0 and the power of 2.4 for the rest - using a power of 2.2 is just some further approximation.

However, the bigger problem with this approach is that `GLubyte` is an 8 Bit unsigned integer type with the range `[0,255]` and doing a `pow(...,2.2)` on that yields a value in `[0,196964.7]`, which when converted back to `GLubyte` will ignore the higher bits and basically calculate the modulo 256, so you will get really useless results. Conceptually, you need `255.0 * pow(x/255.0,2.2)` which could of course be further simplified.

The big problem here is that by doing this conversion, you basically loose a lot of precision due to the non-linear distortion of your value range. 
*If* you do such a conversion before-hand, you would have to use higher precision textures to store the linearized color values (like 16 bit half float per channel), just keeping the stuff as 8bit UNORM is a complete disaster - and that is also why GPUs do the conversion directly when accessing the texture, so that you don't have to blow up the memory footprint of your textures by a factor of 2.

So I really doubt that your approach 3 would be "importing the SRGB textures properly". It will just destroy any fidelity even if done right. Approaches1 and 2 do not have that problem, but approach 1 is just silly considering that the hardware will do that for you for free. so I really wonder why you even consider 1 and 3 at all.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that its not in range 0-1, like in the shader, but as integers instead. I now this method isn't perfect, but for now it will be OK. I am not using method 2 because I pack textures into a texture2dArray for performance, but I will switch at some point to using more than one (preferably sparce bindless texture2dArrays), and then I will be able to use method 2.